# Can't move the cursor up and down after adding a hyperlink in the editor in Firefox

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, editor

Whenever I use the Ctrl+L shortcut or the editor button to add a link in the editor, I can't move the cursor up or down afterwards anymore. This only happens in Firefox (39.0), but not in Opera (30.0.1835.125) or IE11 (11.0.9600.17905).

I have currently no userscripts enabled which might have caused this. This happens on StackOverflow as well as here on MSO and probably all the other sites.

Comment: Reproduced here. left and right arrow continue to work as normal, up and down arrow do nothing.

Comment: Reproduced Firefox 39.0, Windows 8.1. No issues in Chrome.

Comment: Happened to me after inserting a link into the editor by clicking the chain icon. FF 61.0.1 (also happened with older versions), Windows 8.1 Pro. Typing and left/right still work, only up down is a no-op. Using alt-tab to switch to another window and then back, fixes it.